# One repo, multiple directories that contain different languages. Possible to do CD/CI with circle or pipeline in Bitbucket?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, aws-lambda, circleci, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to my structure, but I have a repository titled lambda, which has the following structure:

```
lambda/
    lambda_func_one/
    lambda_func_two/
    ...
    lambda_func_n/
```

Each lambda function is not necessarily in the same language. For example, `lambda_func_one` is in python, while `lambda_func_two` is in node.

Is it achievable to have a continuous deployment/integration of all of these lambda functions? Alternatively I can make them each their own repo, but it's nice to be able to call git pull and see all changes the team made to their respective lambda functions.

Comment: Yes, I should think so. In your `.circleci/config.yml` file, you can set up steps to do pretty much anything. As long as you can install the test tools in the CircleCI environment, and as long as those tools allow you to point to a specific working directory, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, a change in one function triggers the deployment pipeline in other functions as well.
If you still want to keep them in one repo, you can have different branches for each function and setup CI/CD for those branches.

Comment: That's probably not ideal, right? I guess I can make each function it's own repo, but I wish I could have like.... a master repo, that contains a bunch of smaller repos, and if I pull the master repo I pull all the repos inside it ya know? It just seems to make more sense to be able to see all lambda updates vs one at a time

Comment: Different branches per function would be an unusual set-up. The idea with branches is that they will get merged down to a mainline/release branch, which is not possible if they're already being used for sub-features.